openalpr 2.3.0: LNK1104 cannot open file '..\..\..\..\windows\build\dist\2.1.0\v143\Debug\Win32\libtesseract303-static-debug.lib'
In openalpr 2.3 in the C# binding that has a c++ project: alpr-net that builds native assemblies, I get error:

LNK1104   cannot open file
'..\..\..\..\windows\build\dist\2.1.0\v143\Debug\Win32\libtesseract303-static-debug.lib'   openalpr-net    ..\openalpr-2.3.0\src\bindings\csharp\openalpr-net\LINK 1

What is this error and how to correct this?
I also have tesseract54.lib and it also can not open that.
